# Trying to switch between 12V and 5V, CD4066B analog switch

Tags: schematics, switching, texas-instruments, analog-switch

I want to switch between an output of 12V and 5V. I'm using a CD4066B [(datasheet)](http://www.ti.com/document-viewer/CD4066B/datasheet/description-schs0518008#SCHS0518008)

Here's the pinout:

[image: CD4066B pinout]

This is my schematic:
[image: bad schematic, does not achieve desired results]

When I build this circuit, I end up frying the IC. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make this circuit work as desired?

Comment: hmm 12V,5V is this for programming PICs?

Comment: no, this is for a custom circuit that responds differently to different levels of voltage. It needs a constant supply of at least 5V to power a regulator, but if it receives 12V, it powers additional functionality

Comment: if this is to power something you should be using an adjustable voltage regulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're burning it up, because with VSS connectted to 5V  ground is outside the alloable range for an input or outputs. (they must all be between VSS and VDD

there's probably a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to do.
but I have no way to guess what that might be.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxSvDC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

that has the same 120 ohm impedance as the CD4066B switches, but later in comments you say that you 
need to power a device with the output, in this case
an adjustable regulator may be a better choice.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW8n4Y.png)</sup>

Comment: So say I would set VDD as 15V, and keep the input at 12V... do you think would that work? That way the input is between VDD and VSS.

Comment: Also, I like the schematic you made here... I probably could substitute a transistor for the switch and control digitally as I was the analog switch.

Comment: by between, I mean approximately between, equal is allowed, but the performance seems to be a bit weak at the limits.  in my schematic Yes a transisor would work there.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm using a CD4066B ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/document-viewer/CD4066B/datasheet/pin-configuration-and-functions-schs0512378#SCHS0519660))

I see your problem. When the datasheet says pin 7 is the "Low Voltage Power Pin" it means that it is the low*est* voltage power pin - ie. the negative side of the power supply to the chip. And when it says that pin 14 is the "Power Pin" it means the positive side of the power supply. This is required for correct operation of the bilateral switches and drivers, which are powered from Vdd and Vss.

Any pin that strays outside this range will be clamped by its ESD protection diodes (and if too much current flows through them they will be destroyed).

> What can I do to make this circuit work as desired?

Firstly, connect pin 7 to Ground.

The rest is a bit complicated to explain because you need to use two switches, with one being off when the other is on. You can do this with an external inverter, or use one of the spare bilateral switches as an inverter, like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzm4FL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the input control voltage must go from Ground to +12V, because the chip is powered by 12V and the logic gates in it switch states at around 50% of the supply voltage. So your control switch going to +5V must be connected to +12V instead (or you could connect the 100k resistor to +12V and switch it to Ground).

Also note that the bilateral switches have a resistance of ~120 Ω when the chip is powered with 12V. Any current drawn through them will cause a proportional voltage drop. At 10 mA a switch will drop ~1.2 V. In the comments you say:-

> It needs a constant supply of at least 5V to power a regulator, but if
>   it receives 12V, it powers additional functionality

If that regulator and 'additional functionality' draws more than a few milliamps then this chip may not do what you want.

Comment: wow I like this! Uses up a lot of switches, but is slick

Answer (score 1):

CD4066 does not have level shifting. You can use a [CD4053](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf) which allows you to control the higher voltage with a logic level.

Vee = 0V
Vdd = 12V

And connect the inputs to the 2-in MUX to 5V and 12V. Use a series resistor on the control input if it can ever, even momentarily, be present when the 12V supply is lower than the logic input voltage (10K is fine), and add a reverse-biased Schottky diode between the 12V and 5V supplies if the 5V can ever be present when the 12V supply is < 5V.